# Silverlight 4 and parallel port

Tags: silverlight, port, parallel-processing

Is there any class or library for the Silverlight 4 print directly to parallel port (LPT1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless your Silverlight app is a OOB with Elevated Trust and the client has installed on it some COM component that can manipulate the parallel port.

So basically: No.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an OOB Silverlight app with Elevated Trust that can access the local file system, you can make an attempt and dumping data to the parallel port with the file system apis. The name of the LPT device will be **\\.\LPTx** where x is the dos lpt port number that was mapped by windows. You can find this in the registry under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\PARALLEL PORTS** . On my machine it has the key 
\Device\Parallel2 maped to \DosDevices\LPT3 so on I would use the file name "\\.\LPT3" to access the prallel port as if it was a file. Just to be clear that is 2 slashes, a dot then another slash before the port name.